# Mapping an array in react, descending order

Tags: arrays, json, reactjs

I want to use the following data

```
[
  {
      "id": "1",
      "label": "Score",
      "tabledata": [ 
        {"label": "Day 1", "data": {"score": 73}},
        {"label": "Day 2", "data": {"score": 64}},
      {"label": "Day 3", "data": {"score": 72}}
      ]
  }, {
      "id": "2",
      "label": "Success",
      "tabledata": [ 
        {"label": "Day 1", "data": {"score": 73 }},
        {"label": "Day 2", "data": {"score": 64 }},
        {"label": "Day 3", "data": {"score": 72}}
      ]
  } ]
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>    
    <td>
    
    </td>
    <td>
     Score
    </td>
    <td>
     Success
    </td>
   
  </tr>
  
   <tr>    
    <td>
      Day 3
    </td>
    <td>
     72
    </td>
    <td>
     72
    </td>
   
  </tr>
  
   <tr>    
    <td>
      Day 2
    </td>
    <td>
     64
    </td>
    <td>
     64
    </td>
   
  </tr>
 <tr>    
    <td>
      Day 1
    </td>
    <td>
     73
    </td>
    <td>
     73
    </td>
    
  </tr>
  </table>
```

The solution i came up is:

```
 <table >
        <tr>
          <td> </td>
          <td>
            {this.props.GraphData[0].label}
          </td>
          <td>
            {this.props.GraphData[1].label}
          </td>

</tr> 
<tr>
          <td> </td>
          <td>
            {this.props.GraphData[0].tabledata.data.map(row => ([ <tr key={i}>  <td>  {row.score}</td> </tr> )])};
          </td>
          <td>
            {this.props.GraphData[1].tabledata.data.map(row => ([ <tr key={i}>  <td>  {row.score}</td> </tr> )])};
          </td>

</tr> 
</table>
```

How can I turn with reverse.map the values to appear in descending order (the first row (day 3) and last row (day 1). 
Finally is there a way to avoid using [0] or [1] from the data file but to use mapping for all the rows and columns of the table?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you are trying to render out as the final result, but I threw this fiddle together that reverses the order: https://jsfiddle.net/gkysmsqz/31/. Let me know if this is what you are looking for? Your code needs a serious refactor, it needed a lot of work to get it running.

Comment: Or maybe this?? https://jsfiddle.net/gkysmsqz/35/

Comment: @Chase DeAnda thank you ut looks like it's working in JsFiddle but in my app it now has the following issue` TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined`

Comment: Can you post your full code? Are you passing in the data as a prop `GraphData`?

Comment: Exactly i used conditional rendering, so it will only render the element only when it's defined, so i use `{this.props.rowData[0] && (
            <td>
              {this.props.rowData[0].label}
            </td>
          )}` consider GraphData = rowData[0], but now the table won't show on screen.

Comment: so now tha i used `{this.props.rowData[0] &&
            this.props.rowData[0].tabledata.reverse().map((row, i) => (..` it has an error `Cannot read property 'reverse' of undefined`

Answer (score 1):

first of all, your data `structure` is adding complexity as hell, and i advice you to structure it well so you could easily consume it, I've made a refactoring for your code and also restructured your data with a generic way so even `day4, ...dayn` could be shown, that shows well how complex the consumption became if we think generically, so this is what I've got, so rename this file as `Table.jsx` and try to import it as so `import Table from './Table';`:

```
import React from 'react';
import { get, map, reduce, uniq, find, orderBy } from 'lodash';

const data = [
  {
    id: '1',
    label: 'Score',
    tabledata: [
      { label: 'Day 1', data: { score: 73 } },
      { label: 'Day 2', data: { score: 64 } },
      { label: 'Day 3', data: { score: 72 } },
      { label: 'Day 5', data: { score: 60 } }
    ]
  },
  {
    id: '2',
    label: 'Success',
    tabledata: [
      { label: 'Day 1', data: { score: 73 } },
      { label: 'Day 2', data: { score: 64 } },
      { label: 'Day 3', data: { score: 73 } }
    ]
  }
];

const columnsHeaders = ['day', ...map(data, 'label')];

const days = uniq(
  reduce(
    data,
    (acc, item) => [...acc, ...map(get(item, 'tabledata'), 'label')],
    []
  )
);

const restructuredData = reduce(
  days,
  (acc, day) => {
    const dayData = reduce(
      map(data, 'label'),
      (dayDataAcc, colName) => {
        return {
          ...dayDataAcc,
          day,
          [colName]: get(
            find(get(find(data, { label: colName }), 'tabledata'), {
              label: day
            }),
            ['data', 'score']
          )
        };
      },
      {}
    );
    return [...acc, dayData];
  },
  []
);

const sortedData = orderBy(restructuredData, 'day', 'desc');

const TableHeaders = () => (
  <thead>
    <tr>{map(columnsHeaders, (col, index) => <th key={index}>{col}</th>)}</tr>
  </thead>
);

// checking our data
console.log('restructuredData', restructuredData);
console.log('sortedData', sortedData);

const TableRows = ({ data }) => (
  <tbody>
    {map(data, ({ day, Score: score, Success: success }) => (
      <tr key={day}>
        <td>{day || '-'}</td>
        <td>{score || '-'}</td>
        <td>{success || '-'}</td>
      </tr>
    ))}
  </tbody>
);

export default () => (
  <table>
    <TableHeaders />
    <TableRows data={sortedData} />
  </table>
);
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I must load the json file as it (it's not created by me)

Comment: I got it, in this case it's quite tough, especially if you have dynamic data as you see. but it's OK in think.